# code-server 3.6.0 webview script issue with certificate and terminal not running

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, server, webview, code-server

i've just installed code-server 3.6.0 on my ubuntu 16 development server but I'm having issue installing extensions and running terminal:
when I try to install an extension I get the following error:

```
Error loading webview: Could not register service workers: SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://mysite.xxx:8080/webview/') with script ('https://mysite.xxx:8080/webview/service-worker.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script..
```

[image]

when I run code-server by command line ./bin/code-server and login to https://mysite.xxx:8080 I get the following log error:
[image]

I've tried npm rebuil and npm reinstall but the issue is the same
Even the terminal is not running, its always in starting state:
[image]

I previously used version 2.3 of code-server and it was working fine without any issue i could install extensions and run terminals...

anyone is having this issue?
anyone solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completely removed code-server and downloaded the latest version (3.6.2 at the time of  writing).
Run it from ./bin/code-server getting config from ~/.config/code-server/config.yml
and it worked. sometimes still have SErviceWorker error but at least the terminal and major extensions are working fine.